# Kashmir Shivaism: Is the tradition extinct or alive?

Tags: history, tantra, tradition, buddhism, kashmiri-shaivism

During the time of the great philosopher and tantra master, *Abhinavgupta* and Asia's biggest ruler in history, *Lalitaditya*, it was said that Kashmir Shivaism thrived. A very unique blend of Vajrayana Buddhism and Hindu Tantra schools, the doctrine of Vibration (Spanda) was a very unique new variant of Advaita that had emerged that focused on very fast enlightenment and awakening.

After the popular Swami, [Lakshman Joo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshman_Joo) (who officially didn't have any disciples), has the tradition of Kashmir Shivaism survived today's date?

The closest tradition I know of is Nathas, they are still good in Numbers in UP, Bihar, Assam, etc. but I want to know if this school with one of the most beautiful doctrines of the trika system particularly survived modern-day or not after very unfortunate Kashmiri Genocide.

If yes, who are some of the prominent teachers of this system?

---

Edit: [Lakshmanjoo Academy's Kashmir Shivaism](https://www.lakshmanjooacademy.org/kashmir-shaivism)

Comment: Interesting question. Especially relevant in the current time. After the political unification of Kashmir with India, whether any movement is there to revive this authentic spiritual heritage of Kashmir.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay That should happen. Kashmir Shivaism has one of the most beautiful doctrines of the trika system. I know one prof. Timalsina and another prof from Europe (polish) have translated volumes of texts to English. They can put some special effort if needed to revive.

Comment: Kashmiri Shaivism is just no name, that's Trika. And indeed Trika is still very very very much intact. Various guru with adepth knowledge of Trika are still present and initiates their Shishyas. No parampara has ever got extinct, it's just we don't don't know. Well, who are prominent teachers is hard to say, because there are various Gurus teaching Trika Parampara each one as gyani as other. So, it takes research off the line at personal end.

Comment: @Chamundadas Is there any place or authentic mutts that follow spanda doctrines and initiate people? For historical and documentary purposes only, as we all know the unfortunate history of militancy in Kashmir that caused a very huge loss to the culture and philosophy.

Comment: @User29449 Srì Lakshmanjoo's ashram itself is still a biggest hub. Ishwar Ashram in Kashmir, as started by Srì Lakshmanjoo himself is still surviving. And it has branches in Mumbai, Bangalore, and overseas as well. A few more smaller gurus (not known to fame yet equally potent) manages their own parampara.

Comment: @Chamundadas If you can write an answer, then I'd be glad to upvote and accept it! :) Thank you for the information!

Comment: I have sparsely much knowledge on living Trika parampara. Just few friends are dikshit under it so could gather small information. In case if I come across sufficient knowledge on this will post an answer or will keep update in comments.

Comment: @Chamundadas Ah okay, no problem!